# How to send accurate indicator of images to detail for a scroll view

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

I have 2 screens. First one is a collection view of images (I use collection view here). Second one is to show the detail of that images, I can also swipe between each image (I use scroll view here).

I have an array of images which is a global variable.

```
public var images = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]
```

I want to when I click on the item in the first screen, it will show up to the second screen, but at the accurate indicator for a scroll view, because scroll view will contain all images. But I only set the scroll view run from index 0 to images.count - 1. How to set the scroll view show the image that we clicked before from the First screen.

This is my first screen:

I click index 5 and it should be show at the second screen with the index 5 like this (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). But I don't know how to do that.

[image]

And this is my second screen:

[image]

Here is my code in PhotoViewController (FirstScreen):

```
import UIKit
import FXImageView

public var images = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]

class PhotoViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


  @IBOutlet var navigationBar: UIBarButtonItem!
  @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
  //    var images = [String]()

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Story??"
    navigationController!.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 82/255, green: 173/255, blue: 243/255, alpha: 1.0)
    navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]

    //        images = NSMutableArray(array: ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"])
    //        images = ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]
    self.navigationBar.image = UIImage(named: "share")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

  // MARK: Collection
  func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell
    cell.photoImageView.image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
    cell.photoImageView.alpha = 0

    let millisecondDelay = UInt64(arc4random() % 600) / 1000

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(millisecondDelay * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(),({ () -> Void in

      UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: ({
        cell.photoImageView.alpha = 1.0
      }))
    }))
    return cell
  }

  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width/3 - 1.5, height: collectionView.frame.width/3 - 1)
  }

  func collectionView(collection: UICollectionView, selectedItemIndex: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Detail", sender: self)
  }

  override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if segue.identifier == "Detail" {
      let indexPaths = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
      let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
      let photoDetailVC = segue.destinationViewController as! PhotoDetailViewController

      photoDetailVC.photoImage = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])!
    }
  }

  @IBAction func onShareTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

  }   
}
```

And here is my PhotoDetailViewController (SecondScreen):

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AAShareBubbles
import SwipeView

class PhotoDetailViewController: UIViewController, AAShareBubblesDelegate {


  @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  @IBOutlet var topView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var bottomView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet var photoImageView: UIImageView!
  var photoImage = UIImage()
  var checkTapGestureRecognize = true

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    title = "Photo Detail"
    super.viewDidLoad()
    photoImageView.image = photoImage
    scrollPhotoView()
  }

  func scrollPhotoView() {

    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.height)
    //    let scrollViewHeight = self.scrollView.frame.height
    let scrollViewWidth = self.scrollView.frame.width
    let scrollViewHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    for position in 0...images.count - 1 {
      let imageScroll = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth * CGFloat(position), 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
      imageScroll.image = UIImage(named: images[position])
      self.scrollView.addSubview(imageScroll)
    }

    let imagesCount: CGFloat = CGFloat(images.count)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.width * imagesCount, self.scrollView.frame.height)

  }

  @IBAction func onBackClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
  }


  @IBAction func onTabGestureRecognize(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("on tap")
    if checkTapGestureRecognize == true {
      bottomView.hidden = true
      topView.hidden = true
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
      let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
      let screenWidth = screenSize.width
      let screenHeight = screenSize.height
      photoImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
      checkTapGestureRecognize = false
      showAminationOnAdvert()
    }
    else if checkTapGestureRecognize == false {
      bottomView.hidden = false
      topView.hidden = false
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false
      checkTapGestureRecognize = true
    }
  }

  func showAminationOnAdvert() {
    let transitionAnimation = CATransition();
    transitionAnimation.type = kCAEmitterBehaviorValueOverLife
    transitionAnimation.subtype = kCAEmitterBehaviorValueOverLife
    transitionAnimation.duration = 2.5
    transitionAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transitionAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
    photoImageView.layer.addAnimation(transitionAnimation, forKey: "fadeAnimation")

  }


  @IBAction func onShareTouched(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("share")

    let myShare = "I am feeling *** today"

    let shareVC: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [myShare], applicationActivities: nil)
    self.presentViewController(shareVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    //    print("share bubles")
    //    let shareBubles: AAShareBubbles = AAShareBubbles.init(centeredInWindowWithRadius: 100)
    //    shareBubles.delegate = self
    //    shareBubles.bubbleRadius = 40
    //    shareBubles.sizeToFit()
    //    //shareBubles.showFacebookBubble = true
    //    shareBubles.showTwitterBubble = true
    //    shareBubles.addCustomButtonWithIcon(UIImage(named: "twitter"), backgroundColor: UIColor.whiteColor(), andButtonId: 100)
    //    shareBubles.show()

  }

  @IBAction func playAutomaticPhotoImages(sender: AnyObject) {
    scrollView.hidden = true
    animateImages(0)
  }

  func animateImages(no: Int) {
    var number: Int = no
    if number == images.count - 1 {
      number = 0
    }
    let name: String = images[number]
    self.photoImageView!.alpha = 0.5
    self.photoImageView!.image = UIImage(named: name)

    //code to animate bg with delay 2 and after completion it recursively calling animateImage method
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.8, options:UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: {() in
      self.photoImageView!.alpha = 1.0;
      },
      completion: {(Bool) in
        number++;
        self.animateImages(number);
        print(String(images[number]))
    })
  }


}
```

May anyone help me with this?

Comment: simple just move selected index to second view controller execute the for loop based your index value and shows into scrollview thats all, would you need the code for this

Answer (score 1):

**Step-1**

on your `PhotoDetailViewController` create one global `Int` for get the clicked Index, like

```
var slideCount: Int! = 0
```

**Step-2**

assign the selected index to slide count on your first view controller, like

```
photoDetailVC.photoImage = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])!
photoDetailVC. slideCount =  indexPath.row // assign the selected index.
```

**Step-3**

on your `PhotoDetailViewController`

```
  for position in 0...images.count - 1 {

   if position > slideCount  // the array executed only on your selected index count 
   {
  let imageScroll = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(scrollViewWidth * CGFloat(position), 0, scrollViewWidth, scrollViewHeight))
  imageScroll.image = UIImage(named: images[position])
  self.scrollView.addSubview(imageScroll)

   }
}
```

Comment: The photoImage is behind the scrollView. Should I use collectionview in photodetailviewcontroller instead of scrollview?

Comment: in my knowledge no need of photoImage on separate , just remove and try once

Comment: Yes, but I haven't deleted it yet, just try scrollView work well. But is there a good way to use collectionview in this case instead of scrollview, because it has this function func collectionView(collection: UICollectionView, selectedItemIndex: NSIndexPath)??

Comment: collection view , tableview , web view  is the subclass of scrollview if you want to access directly you can do it . but you are in right way on your work , but in this concept this is the correct way  ...., else ur wish....